# how can i split querydata in node.js function using : as the splitter and creat 2 seprate string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, split

okay so here is my node.js script

```
  // Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
  var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + queryData.name + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end(stdout);

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8283);
```

basically I want to be able to split querydata.name into to seprate variable to use in the exec

here is an example of what I want to do

```
split querydata.name into 
value1
and
value2
```

so I can use them like this

```
exec ("casperjs test.js " + value1 + " " + value2 + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr)
```

can anyone help me achieve this the string needs splitting using : as the splitter

```
----------------------EDIT CODE I HAVE TRIED this now works edited again ---------------------------------



var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var basevalue = queryData.name;
    var value = basevalue.split (":");
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + value[0] + " " + value[1] + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end(stdout);

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8283);
```

and the error I get

```
[root@cyber-hosted ~]# node no1.js

/root/no1.js:1
on (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var server = http.creat
                                                                ^
ReferenceError: http is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/no1.js:1:76)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
[root@cyber-hosted ~]#
```

I just cannot get the split working correctly

Comment: yes I have looked at the split() function I am new to js and I am struggling to do it I have tried a few things I have see around the web but seem to always break my script and cannot achieve the split

Comment: What code did you try? What problem did you have?

Comment: @SLaks I have updated the code above with what I have tried and the error

Comment: @SLaks anychance you can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the split. The stacktrace you posted states `ReferenceError: http is not defined`.

This is because you need to require any modules you use in your code.

If you add the line `var http = require('http')` to the top of your file, it should fix the problem.

edit: You'll need to add `var url = require('url')` as well.

edit2: Tested this code, it should work:

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8283/?name=Tom

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + queryData.name + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end(stdout);

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

server.listen(8283);
```

Comment: @user3316689 I just edited my answer. You also need to add the line: var url = require('url')

Comment: okay so I done the above the script works but the two split strings are not being passed

Comment: when I ask casper to echo the result of the post data it say NaN wich means it is not receiving it

Comment: @user3316689 Have you tried console logging your values before passing them to casper to make sure they are as expected...? This is really just basic debugging stuff- perhaps you should do a bit more reading on node/javascript before you try using more complicated frameworks like casper.

Comment: here is the output I get and also I have already configured my casperjs script wich works perfectly fine . I am learning node for my fronted

Comment: console.log(value[0]);
    console.log(value[1]);
    console.log(value[2]);

Comment: @user3316689 I just tried running your code. The issue is that queryData.name isn't actually separated by colons. queryData.name is equal to 'Tom' using the commented example. So instead of passing value[0] and value[1] into casper, just pass queryData.name. Doing this worked fine for me. Edit: I'll edit my working code into the answer.